# Android MVP best way to handle views with API call

Tags: java, android, mvp

I am having a question regarding how do I update my view or perform a fragment transition when the view goes to background and the API response comes as a callback.

For example I have a loginfragment. User clicks login button and the presenter takes it and gives it Interactor where I have my Rx observer who talks to repository and model and so on. The response comes back in maybe 3 to 5 seconds. Within this time, I press home button and my app goes to background. The presenter receives the response from Interactor callback and now wants to update the view but view is in background.

On login success, I want to make a fragment transition and go to Fragment B. But my view is in background. So when I bring my app back to foreground, I still see login screen although I already got a login success API response.

How do I handle view updates or fragment transition when view goes to background and what is the best way of doing it?

Comment: Maybe you can persist a token locally after the login, so that when you bring the application to the foreground, you can check that you're already authenticated and do that fragment transition.

Comment: That's for login...but what about other API calls ? For example the ones with http success code 204 (no content) ? Should I persist every http response locally ?

Comment: Actually, even having no content, you will still be able to know if the call succeeded or not. So the aim is to persist anything that can help you knowing the last state of your network request, to know what to display / change in your UI when you come back in the app. For a request responding `204`, using a simple boolean can do the job, or queuing an action to execute later. This is a wide question to answer, as every single request will have a different result.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is Model-View-Intent architecture in [Mosby](https://proandroiddev.com/writing-reactive-apps-with-mvi-f7de70739d59), in which the presenter stores the latest state of the view, and the view subscribes to the ViewState Observable in order to update. In such approach the view can subscribe in `onStart()`, when it is safe to make fragment transactions.

Another possible approach is that each view has a state (ViewState), that holds a queue of commands to the view. If the view is ready (`onStart()` was already called), then the command is passed to it immediately, otherwise it is saved to a queue and postponed until the view is ready. See how it is realized in [Moxy](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy/wiki).